# Haskell websockets library not working

Tags: haskell, websocket, functional-programming

I was able to successfully use the `websockets` library with https://www.websocket.org/echo.html. I can also connect to api2.poloniex.com via https://www.websocket.org and successfully query the websocket.

However when I try to connect to api2.poloniex.com with `websockets` I get the following error:

```
Exception: MalformedResponse (ResponseHead {responseCode = 403, responseMessage = "Forbidden", responseHeaders = [("Date","Wed, 15 Aug 2018 00:27:10 GMT"),("Content-Type","text/html; charset=UTF-8"),("Transfer-Encoding","chunked"),("Connection","close"),("CF-Chl-Bypass","1"),("Set-Cookie","__cfduid=de2aa54a27d656c35f2c3b90f60cc72461534292830; expires=Thu, 15-Aug-19 00:27:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.poloniex.com; HttpOnly"),("Cache-Control","max-age=2"),("Expires","Wed, 15 Aug 2018 00:27:12 GMT"),("X-Frame-Options","SAMEORIGIN"),("Server","cloudflare"),("CF-RAY","44a788b174052eb7-MIA")]}) "Wrong response status or message."
```

My code is as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main
    ( main
    ) where

import           Control.Concurrent  (forkIO)
import           Control.Monad       (forever, unless)
import           Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Text           (Text)
import qualified Data.Text           as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO        as T
import           Network.Socket      (withSocketsDo)
import qualified Network.WebSockets  as WS


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app :: WS.ClientApp ()
app conn = do
    putStrLn "Connected!"

    -- Fork a thread that writes WS data to stdout
    _ <- forkIO $ forever $ do
        msg <- WS.receiveData conn
        liftIO $ T.putStrLn msg

    -- Read from stdin and write to WS
    let loop = do
            line <- T.getLine
            unless (T.null line) $ WS.sendTextData conn line >> loop

    loop
    WS.sendClose conn ("Bye!" :: Text)


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ WS.runClient "api2.poloniex.com" 80 ""  app
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like that the Poloniex WebSocket API requires a secure connection, see: https://poloniex.com/support/api/ (I know this from the WS endpoint URL, it uses `wss://` instead of `ws://`). `WS.runClient` uses the unsecure `ws://` protocol instead of the secure `wss://` one and thus it won't be able to connect. Try using the wuss library: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wuss
and rewrite your main function to:

```
import qualified Wuss as WSS (runSecureClient)
-- ...
main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ WSS.runSecureClient "api2.poloniex.com" 443 "/" app
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made the changes but then GHC spat out this:
```*** Exception: HandshakeFailed (Error_Packet_Parsing "Failed reading: invalid header type: 72\nFrom:\theader\n\n")```

Comment: @Jimbo I could reproduce the issue. Try the following (it worked for me):
`main = withSocketsDo $ WSS.runSecureClient "api2.poloniex.com" 443 "/" app`.
LMK if it worked and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Jimbo and you didn't forget to add the path "/", right? If so, can you tell me the version Network.Socket, Network.WebSockets and Wuss that you use?

Comment: the path is "/" and these are my versions: network 2.6.3.6,
wuss 1.1.10 @KyloRAM https://pastebin.com/iaTT8qL9

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the problem but before I do that: how do you build your program?

Comment: I use stack. Thanks for taking the time to help me btw!

Comment: Sure, no worries! Can you try loading your Main.hs into ghci (`ghci Main.hs`)? This way, we will have a more or less clean build and can go from there.

Comment: Yep I can load Main.hs via `ghci Main.hs`. I still get the same error if I run `main`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178141/discussion-between-kyloram-and-jimbo).

Answer (score 2):

The issue was for whatever reason my public IP was being blocked. I got around this by using a VPN.